# How to do an IF calculation in SQL Select?

Tags: sql, select

My select statement starts as follows:

> `select Number, Number*2 as NumberTimes2 from Table1 ...`

If I want NumberTimes2 to be 100 when Number*2 >= 100, how do I code this in the select statement? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select
  Number,
  case when Number > 50 then 100 else Number * 2 end as NumberTimes2
from Table1
...
```

All flavours of SQL allow a `CASE` statement (you haven't stated which database you are using). Depending on your database, you may be able to do it in a briefer way (for example mysql's `if` statement)